# Error with simple PHP form with MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, forms

Sirs,

I'm getting an error from my PHP script, probably the query, but I can't figure out what's going on. I can connect the database, but I still get the error from de "echo ERROR" line.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code? I appreciate any help! I spent a few hours to solve this issue, but couldn't get nothing.

**HTML form**

```
<form action="insert-info.php" method="post">
<input class="form1" type="text" value="TEXT ONE" name="textone" onfocus="if (this.value=='NTEXT ONE') this.value='';"/>
<input class="form1" type="text" value="TEXT TWO" name="texttwo" onfocus="if (this.value=='TEXT TWO') this.value='';"/>
<input class="form2" type="text" value="TEXT THREE" name="textthree" onfocus="if (this.value=='TEXT THREE') this.value='';"/>
</form>
```

**Database connect and insert**

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="***"; // Mysql username 
$password="***"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="***"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="insertinfo"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form 
$textone=$_POST['textone'];
$texttwo=$_POST['texttwo'];
$textthree=$_POST['textthree'];

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name('textone', 'texttwo', 'textthree') VALUES ('$textone', '$texttwo', '$textthree')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<br />";
echo "<a href='insert.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

**Database structure**

```
#   Type                    Collation   Null            Pattern     Extra
1   id int(4)                           None            (none)      AUTO_INCREMENT
2   textone varchar(50)     utf8_bin    None            (none)  
3   texttwo varchar(50)     utf8_bin    None            (none)
4   textthree varchar(50)   utf8_bin    None            (none)
```

Comment: you're query is open to sql injections. Please learn to use `prepared statements` or `mysqli` instead of mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the issue is just the column names of your INSERT query. You don't need single quotes around those.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(textone, texttwo, textthree) VALUES ('$textone', '$texttwo', '$textthree')";
```

That should work.

EDIT: echo_Me and Mayank's warnings and recommendations are necessary to consider for production code!

Comment: Thankyou! I solved the issue. I'll work with Mayank's tips now, even if that system will not be online (it's just for internal use).

Comment: @Anna Great! It's always fun to experiment, but do remember to be wary of security when it comes to production systems (you don't want to lose any important data!). PDO and MySQLi help a lot to avoid common mistakes and also offer many conveniences over the old MySQL driver.

Comment: I appreciate your advice, Russellc! I'll try to implement using the code that Vipin Soni posted here.

Answer (score 0):

actually you are not selecting database and the connection variables. because you are using strings. you need to remove the quotes like that

```
  mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
  mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
```

there is some things you need to fix in your code .

- escape your POST variables.
- change to PDO or MYSQLI.
- follow the error by echoing system error.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_error() to print the error message. It will tell you more about why the query failed. Note that this function is deprecated. I recommend to use mysqli or PDO database classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql=sprintf(
"INSERT INTO 
        $tbl_name(textone, texttwo, textthree) 
        VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')", 
mysql_real_escape_string($textone), 
mysql_real_escape_string($texttwo), 
mysql_real_escape_string($textthree)
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try tu use this.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Like this**

There is no need to give `column` `names` within `' '`  in `INSERT` query.

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(textone,texttwo,textthree) VALUES ('$textone', '$texttwo', '$textthree')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
```